# Toast Message pops up when holding Action Bar Button

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, toast

I have an app and when I press and hold on of the buttons I have put on the action bar this weird blank message pops up and looks like this.

When I tap and hold the profile button that weird empty box pops up and then disappears like a toast?

[image]

But no where in my activity do I set anything to pop up...?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an automatic "tool-tip"-style hint for the user, put on all your action items. Set the `title` attribute in your menu resource (e.g., `android:title` for the native action bar) to fill in the string resource to appear there.